error on airflow dag while running dag on single day : HIVE_TOO_MANY_OPEN_PARTITIONS
I'm using the DBT Pipeline along with an airflow DAG. The SQL query operates smoothly without any DBT code. However, when I execute the DAG for a single day, it throws an error labeled HIVE_TOO_MANY_OPEN_PARTITIONS. I've implemented partitioning based on the date, and since I'm only running the DAG for a single day, it ideally should create only one partition. I'm unsure why Athena is generating multiple partitions.
I'm utilizing DBT and Airflow, and there might be a minor detail that I'm overlooking.
Here's the DBT model configuration:
{{ config(materialized='incremental', incremental_strategy='insert_overwrite', partitioned_by=['event_date'], external_location='location') }}

error message:
 HIVE_TOO_MANY_OPEN_PARTITIONS: Exceeded limit of 100 open writers for partitions/buckets. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://dbt/temp/tables/c2311026-c464-4a2b-a59a-f3aef7fa9fd8' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

Another thing to note is that I haven't specified the S3 location in the code. The actual location provided in the code is different, and I'm uncertain where Athena is picking up this location from.
checks from my side:

SQL works fine
I have mentioned the pipeline name in schema.yml
S3 location mentioned is present in s3

any help is appreciated
please let me know if you need any additional information from my side to get to the bottom

I'm haven't used dbt with Airflow, but if you're using the dbt-athena package I've gotten around that error by setting force_batch = 'true'.
Documentation for table configuration where force_batch is referenced is here
